# DB2 simple Select SP

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

i try to get an SP to run on DB2 connected with Squirrel

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BOCA.TESTSP
(IN CASID INTEGER)
 READS SQL DATA
 DETERMINISTIC
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN 
 SELECT * FROM BOCA.TCASE C WHERE C.ID = CASID
END;
```

I get various errors based on where I put the ; (at end of statement etc)

i tried to follow this approach:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [qualifier.]<procedure_name>
([IN | OUT | INOUT <argument_name> <datatype>,...])
{MODIFIES SQL DATA |
 NO SQL |
 CONTAINS SQL |
 READS SQL DATA}
[[NOT] DETERMINISTIC]
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN [ATOMIC]
  <procedure_body>
END
```

But did not succeed.
Anyone have a simple select that runs?

Stange is that an sample update I was able to create

Comment: SP is a compound statement. You must: 1. Change the default statement termination character `;` to some another one like `@` (find where it is in Squirrel or whatever tool you use) and use it after the outer `END`. 2. Close every statement inside the SP with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to study the sample code that IBM supplies for SQL PL procedures, get these samples built and working in your environment. The samples are in the documentation, also they are on github,  also they are in the SAMPLES directory of your Db2-server installation (for DB2 on Linux/Unix/Windows).

Your procedure has some mistakes:

- missing statement separator after the SELECT statement
- incorrect usage of SELECT in a routine. You either want to declare and open a cursor to return a result set to the caller or client, or you want to use SELECT...INTO to process the result of the query inside your routine.
- missing valid separator at the end of the block of code (after the final END)

For `SQuirrel SQL Client`, before you connect to the database:

```
File > New Session Properties > SQL

(scroll down the list of properties until you see:
Statement Separator ;

Change the Statement Separator to @
Click OK.
```

Now connect to the database.

When you then type any SQL statement inside Squirrel (or a block, such as a trigger, stored-procedure, user defined function etc), you must now use the new statement separator instead of the previous default value **at the end of the whole statement**.

Inside of your routines , you will still need to use the semicolon to delimit statements **inside** the block, but remember to specify the new statement separator at the end of the block (after the final END in the stored procedure in your case).